# How do I tie survey data to a coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, dwg, land-survey

I have Record of Survey drawings from Marin County that I can plot in CAD, but I am not sure the best/easiest way to place the lot lines into a coordinate space.  I found some benchmarks in the County GIS (see image pasted at bottom), but I don't see them referenced into any of the surveys.  Likewise I can see street survey monuments on the drawings, but I can't find any database that has those monuments, or has them with coordinates.  The County provides parcel shapefiles with their GIS, but those are off by 15+ feet in the area of interest.  This is evident when the Assessor's maps (in black) are compared with the County GIS parcel outlines (in red).

[image]

[image]

Comment: What GIS software are you using to try and do this?

Comment: @PolyGeo I'm trying to provide a .dwg that someone can import to ArcGIS

Comment: Link please to your data. What software, what have you tried, what didn't work?

Comment: This is the parcel map: https://apps.marincounty.org/mapbooks/book193/193-17.pdf.  The County has parcels data (https://gisopendata.marincounty.gov/maps/marincounty::parcels) but it is very poor in this area.  I can draft the parcel map but I don't have an easy way to tie it back to the State Plane.

Comment: "off by 15+ feet". Compared to what? What software are you using? What steps are you using to import that shape data?

Comment: @Pointdump the comparison is through visual overlay.  See the image added to the question

Comment: You could use a software like QGIS and look at georegerencong images or rasters. The choice of coordinate system can make a difference sometimes and show that the data is off. You could readjust it manually with the georeferecing tools.

Comment: "the comparison is through visual overlay" In what software? "off by 15+ feet" In the center of that parcel shapefile the difference between International Feet and US Survey Feet is almost 13 feet.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to get GeoJSON for desired parcels:

- Go to https://gisopendata.marincounty.gov/datasets/marincounty::parcels/explore?location=37.907664%2C-122.684449%2C15.97
- Zoom to Bolinas:
  [image]
- Select desired area:
  [image]
- Click on **Filter to this area**.
- Click on cloud download symbol on the left toolbar and select **Toggle Filters**:
  [image]
- On the left scroll down to GeoJSON and click **Download**:
  [image]
- It will take some time, but at the end you'll get GeoJSON for your selected parcels.

Here is a sample from created GeoJSON:

```js
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "name": "Parcels",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "OBJECTID": 2371531,
        "Parcel": "19313334",
        "Prop_ID": "193-133-34",
        "SHAPE_Length": 0.0009797248028444298,
        "SHAPE_Area": 1.1636434035516913e-8
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -122.68696252399997,
                37.90567021700008
              ],
              [
                -122.68706740799996,
                37.90567134400004
              ],
```

For download format you can of course also select KML, Shapefile or Geodatabase.

This is how resultant GeoJSON looks likewhen displayed on https://geojson.io/:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful, but the County parcel data is quite a bit off which is why I am trying to draft and reference from survey data.  Any thoughts on how to tie it in?

Comment: What do you mean by "way off"? If I drop it on geojson.io site, it seems to match exactly as your image. See edited answer.

Comment: The image I had pasted was from the GIS browser, but it was just to show the monuments.  I added an image to the question for clarification

Comment: You have to find points where your parcels match with official parcel plan and use them to georeference you plan.